# How to connect between two document libraries in different webapplications using BCS?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs

In Sharepoint 2010 , How to connect between two document libraries in different webapplications using BCS?. The webapplications has sitecollections and sites in it and the sites are getting created programmatically through custom UI.The document libraries mentioned above are situated in the programmatically created sites.

Comment: what do you mean by "connect the libraries"?

Comment: i need to replicate the content of the document library 1 to document library 2.

Comment: 0down votefavorite

 



In sharepoint 2010, Need to have a document library in a site and another document library in another site and the 2nd document library should be an exact copy of the 1st document library(with the doucments) in it. When 1st document library is updated with documents , 2nd document library should also populated with the changes made in document library 1. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anu,

You should create an Event Receiver on your 1st Document Library and pro-grammatically perform the changes on the 2nd document library...

[Read about Event Receivers here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx)

And inside the ItemAdded or ItemUpdated event, you can replicate the changes programmatically to the 2nd document library, pseudo code can look like:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    if (properties.ListTitle == "FirstDocumentLibrary")
    {
        using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(strUrl))
        {
             using(SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
             {
                 //Get file from properties.ListItem

                 //Upload file code
             }
        }
    }
}
```